# How to change font parameters in Z axis?

Tags: matplotlib

I'm trying to personalize some of my graphs so I'd like to change the font of all axis. I wrote the code below for that. The problem is that I can't change the font of the z axis. Somebody have a recommendation?

Thanks in advance.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import cm

font = {'size'   : 12}

cm=1/2.54

size_x = 10*cm
size_y = 8*cm
min_limx = 4
max_limx = 10
min_limy = 0
max_limy = 50
min_limz = 0
max_limz = 8
#%%
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(size_x, size_y), subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})
X, Y = np.meshgrid(xnew, ynew, indexing='ij')
Z1 = m_fill
Z2 = m_nofill
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z1, cmap=cm.viridis, linewidth=0, antialiased=False)
surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z2, color='w', linewidth=0, antialiased=False)

ax.set_xlabel('$\lambda$', **font)
ax.set_ylabel('$\chi$', **font)
ax.set_zlabel('$\it{m_{0}, кг}$', **font)

lin_x = np.arange(min_limx, max_limx, step=2)
lin_y = np.arange(min_limy, max_limy, step=15)

plt.xticks(lin_x, **font)
plt.yticks(lin_y, **font)
#plt.zticks(lin_z, **font) # AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'zticks'
ax.set_zlim(0, 8, )


#plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
ax.view_init(45, -45)
#plt.tight_layout()
plt.grid()
plt.show()
fig.savefig('p0_V_m0.png', format='png', dpi=300)
```

Ps: This is how the figure looks like right now.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The fontsize of the tick labels is [set](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.html?highlight=tick_params#mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d.Axes3D.tick_params) by the [`labelsize`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html#matplotlib-axes-axes-tick-params) parameter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={"projection": "3d"})

font = {'size': 20}
ax.tick_params('z', labelsize=font['size'])
```

[image]

(To set the label size for all three axes you can use `ax.tick_params(labelsize=20)`.)